# Why doesn't Serial.read() read multiple character?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I used multiple of Serial.read() and Serial.parseInt() to get characters and a number ( like "xy123" ) on an Arduino UNO.
Then I checked the result on Serial monitor.

Unfortunately I couldn't get the character with second Serial.read().

Here's the code:

```
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){  
  if (Serial.available() >0) {

    // I want to reacive the characters like "xy123"
    char input1 = Serial.read();
    char input2 = Serial.read();
    int value = Serial.parseInt();

    Serial.println(input1); // ok
    Serial.println(input2); // * no good * (-1)
    Serial.println(value);  // ok

    // Writing some codes with input1 ,input2 and value ...        
  }
// I don't want to use delay(). 
}
```

How do I get the second character?

Thanks.

Comment: Everything is explained here: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Comment: what second character?

Answer (score 3):

```
  if (Serial.available() >0) {
```

This is like saying "I won't go into that room until there is at least one dog in there".  Someone tells you there is a dog there. You go into the room and say "Hey, why aren't there **two** dogs there?".

If you want to read two bytes one approach is to wait until they are available:

```
  if (Serial.available() >= 2) {
```

Comment: but you did send two dogs into the tunnel leading to that room :-)

Comment: Exactly! But one hasn't arrived yet. :) Dogs move at a finite speed, the same way that serial communications does. In fact I think **everything** moves at a finite speed.

Answer (score 2):

You did not read the second character, because the character did not arrive yet. Wait until it is available. `read` doesn't wait. `parseInt` has the waiting build-in.

You can wait for the second character by reading the two characters with the waiting function `readBytes`. It will wait a second for the next character.

```
char buff[2];
if (Serial.readBytes(buff, 2) == 2) {
  char input1 = buff[0];
  char input2 = buff[1];
...
```

If you send only one character, readBytes will wait one second for the next and the returns that one char was read.